# Armature Not Deforming Mesh

Tags: mesh, armature

There are about 102 questions about the armature not deforming the mesh, and I have tried every single one of them. And It's still. Not. Working.

I have utterly no clues as to why the armature isn't deforming the mesh (I've included the file, so you all can play around with it), and the entire mesh has a series of vertex groups - of which all of the bone names match.

I am honestly so confused. The only bone I can get to deform anything at the shoulder.l and shoulder.r. Absolutely nothing else.

If anyone could help, that'd be greatly appreciated!

[Here's the link!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xWYGHxmWZpV20wMVd4U0tQekU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Misha welcome to Blender SE.  There's two things preventing seeing the deformations in your armature:

1. You have the manipulator set to 'Manipulate Centre Points' (see picture below).  That will prevent any rotations from happening in a chain of parented bones, who's pivots are all dependent on their parents' tails.  Uncheck this box:
   [image]
2. Your armature modifier settings have all their deformations based on the Abdoman bone.  This means the Abdoman's vertex influences are determining the deformation of the entire model.  I suspect you don't actually want this, unless your gearing up for a more complicated modifier stack.  Just hit the 'X' next to the Abdoman bone to clear that out.
   [image]

After that you should see that your model now deforms the way you intended.   Happy Blender-ing!

Comment: Yes, what he said. Plus the hand bones dont have bone weights assigned yet